# Realm.io and compound primary keys

Tags: ios, swift, entity, realm

I'm using Realm for Swift 1.2, and I'm wondering how to implement a compound primary key for an entity.

So you specify your primary key by overriding `primaryKey()`

```
override static func primaryKey() -> String? { // <--- only 1 field
    return "id"
}
```

The only way I can see is to create another compound attribute like so

```
var key1 = "unique thing"
var key2 = 123012

lazy var key: String? = {
    return "\(self.key1)\(self.key2)"
}()

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "key"
}
```

How do you properly supply compound keys in Realm?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that is the correct way to return a compound key in Realm.

Here's the answer from Realm : https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1192

> You could use a mix of lazy and didSet instead to have the compoundKey
>   property be both derived and stored:
>
> ```
> public final class Card: Object {
>     public dynamic var id = 0 {
>         didSet {
>             compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
>         }
>     }
>     public dynamic var type = "" {
>         didSet {
>             compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
>         }
>     }
>     public dynamic lazy var compoundKey: String = self.compoundKeyValue()
>     public override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
>         return "compoundKey"
>     }
>
>     private func compoundKeyValue() -> String {
>         return "\(id)-\(type)"
>     }
> }
>
> // Example
>
> let card = Card()
> card.id = 42
> card.type = "yolo"
> card.compoundKey // => "42-yolo"
> ```

Comment: From jpsim at realm github: "Realm won't actually call willSet and didSet once those objects are persisted, so you'll have to use custom setters"

Comment: "beginning from Realm Swift 1.0.1, you can't use lazy properties anymore due to interoperability issues with the Objective-C runtime"
 https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1192#issuecomment-323322317

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer needs an update (regarding didSet and lazy)

Taken from "mrackwitz" at Realm git-hub: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1192 :

```
public final class Card: Object {
    public dynamic var id = 0
    public func setCompoundID(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }
    public dynamic var type = ""
    public func setCompoundType(type: String) {
        self.type = type
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue() 
    }
    public dynamic var compoundKey: String = "0-"
    public override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "compoundKey"
    }

    private func compoundKeyValue() -> String {
        return "\(id)-\(type)"
    }
}
```